# Order of cvScalar

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

My Img in an IplImage*

Do you confirm that the right order of what is follow:

- x and y: x for the width and y for the height of the image?
- B, G and R : the order of OpenCV in colors?

  ```
  CvScalar scal = cvGet2D(img, x, y);
  blue_lum=scal.val[0];
  green_lum=scal.val[1];
  red_lum=scal.val[2];
  ```
- The order of a 3Channel image? Channel 1 is B and Channel 3 is R ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this (core_c.h Ln 1264):

```
#define CV_RGB( r, g, b )  cvScalar( (b), (g), (r), 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

order of CvScalar is RGB whereas order of imread method in opencv is BGR.

Comment: Canberk Baci Then. scal.val[0] is for RED and scal.val[2] is for GREEN?

Comment: I think you want to get pixel color intensities here. I believe get2d returns the BGR order; so your assignment was true. I thought you were asking cvScalar constructor, which creates RGB. Why don't you test it with a whole-blue image and see?

Comment: But I can assure you if you want to use 'scal' as a color input to a method, it will be wrong. Use cvtColor(img,img, CV_BGR2RGB); before anything to get out of confusion